# What is the antonym of "digital native"?

Tags: antonyms, internet

A *digital native* is someone who has grown up with all the new technologies, like the Internet, and has no troubles adapting to new ones.

Yet there is still are quite a few who never really got in touch with these technologies; people born in the 60s and 70s, who still buy their music on CD, watch TV on a television, and only read news printed on paper.

So I am not looking for *digital immigrant*, as those people I want to describe aren't even discovering this new technology yet. They are still oblivious about them.

How would I call them?

Comment: So, basically, you're looking for a new pejorative term to use against your parents? Voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: related: [Is there a word for a non-geek?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50818/is-there-a-word-for-a-non-geek)

Comment: @Robusto I am not looking for a "pejorative term" but "just a term to describe them", that labels how they are beyond good and evil. How did my question make you think I am looking for a pejorative term?

Comment: digital tourist?

Comment: Okay, digital native. Can you tell me how I can watch TV Japan (NHK) in North America without a cable TV subscription? Maybe you have a good hack for that. (I mean watch in real time, not select things that someone ripped and seeded via Bittorrent, days or weeks later.) I tried via some site that re-broadcast it, but the quality was so poor it was unwatchable. Fact is, if you think TV has gone away, you're the digital naive. You can watch lots of stuff on the Internet, but it's not TV.

Comment: go with luddite, or digital luddite

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the second *t* from *digital native* and you have your answer. So you’d have someone who was a *digital naïve*, or perhaps a *digital naïf* if male.

*Digitally naïve* sounds like a pretty good way to describe someone. I guess you could also neologue  *cybersavvy* (as an adjective) or some such, but I think existing words suffice here.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much describes me, and I would call myself 
[a late adopter.](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=8&gs_id=t&xhr=t&q=late+adopter&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=late+ada&aq=0s&aqi=g-s4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=256a287b594d26f7&biw=1366&bih=524)

Of course that implies that we late adopters eventually get there. So if you're wanting a word for someone who never will use some of these innovations or is actually against innovation, that could be a *Luddite*.

[From the Wikipedia entry:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luddite) In modern usage, "Luddite" is a term describing those opposed to industrialisation, automation, computerisation or new technologies in general.

Comment: Think you're oblivious about the Internet? But in fact you are already there now my friend!

Comment: I do use the Internet (*an ocean an inch deep*), but I do all the other things the OP mentions.